# Shell scripting while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging

```
 #!/bin/sh
   export TERM=linux
   start()
   {
   logger "starting logs..."
   NOW=$(date +"%F")
   FILE="log-$NOW"
   sh -ci "myapp -w /opt/home/logs/$FILE &> /dev/tty${#} &" >> /dev/null
   wait
   logger "myapp started"
   }

   stop()
   {
   kill -9 $(pidof myapp)
   }
   CDAY=$(date +"%d")
   start
   while [1]; do
        if [ $CDAY -ne $(date +"%d") ]
        then
                logger "loop"
                CDAY=$(date +"%d")
                stop; start
        fi
   done
```

the logic is next:
myapp starts to log some process
if current day has been changed (next day came) script stops myapp and launch it again for new log file creation

I am new with shell scripting and it doesn't work as assumed, where am I wrong?

UPD: seems that while loop doesn't work, script doesn't go in it, no `logger "loop"` in logread

**UPDD:** done
corrected syntax of while loop to
`while :` and it starts to work.
Thank you all!

Comment: Please describe how your script doesn't work as assumed.

Comment: I think you forgot a `$`: `/dev/tty${#}` assuming you want the number of arguments passed.

Comment: @gareth_bowles I started it yesterday and assumed that today I will see 2 log files for 28th and 29th of May. But I see only logfile for 28th and myapp is continuing to write in it

Comment: Since you want a numeric match you should do `(( $CDAY != $(date +"%d") ))` and for better style a function called stop should not start also. Either rename to `restart` or use `stop; start` in the while loop.

Comment: @RedX could you explain more regarding (( ))? should I change [] brackets to (( )) ?

Comment: @kumarich This may be of some help. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

Comment: it seems that while loop doesn't work, added it with logger `loop` and do not see anything in logread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>My wild stab in the dark would be to remove the `fi` on the last line, as it doesn't seem to have a matching `if`.</strike> You might benefit from adding a `sleep 120` or so to your while loop, otherwise you're going to be wasting CPU time doing it as fast as possible with little upside. The error might be with `if [ $CDAY !=$(date +"%d") ]`, I believe you have to have a space on either side of your operator, like this: `if [ $CDAY != $(date +"%d") ]`. Since you're doing integer comparison, you should probably also change your operator to `-ne` because `!=` is used for string comparison. I'd recommend changing the `%d` to `%M` so that it will roll over much more quickly, which is good for making sure it works. (`%F` will also need to be changed to something more specific, like `%c`).

Comment: last line with 'fi' is an error of copying it from putty, in the real script it doesn't exist, sorry for that. Thank you for hint with 'sleep 120'

Comment: changed to `if (( $CDAY -ne $(date +"%M") ))` in file creation also to "%M" but no luck. It creates one file and write all data in it

Comment: Try using either `(( $CDAY != $(date +"%M") ))` or `[ $CDAY -ne $(date +"%M") ]`

Comment: with launched myapp created script `echo $(pidof myapp)` and script echo'ed nothing